# Rails: client_side_validations being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation

I'm using client_side_validations on my sign up form. When a user signs up they are required to have an email. But if they authenticate with twitter through omniauth which doesn't give emails, they are redirected back to a failing validation form on my signup page that says "Email cant be blank".

If I click out of the email form field without entering anything a second "Email can't be blank" appears after the first message.

How can I make sure the validations are only called once and never pile on top of eachother?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open an issue on Github? https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues so we can continue the conversation there?